# Tradeoff between continuous buffered read and partial read plus seek

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, buffer, seek

I have a large binary file (say 1 GB) composed of concatenated elements of the type:

```
| -------- element 1 --------| ------- element 2 -------- | ...
| length (uint32) | contents | length (uint32) | contents | ...
```

The contents are of course of variable lengths.

I am scanning through the file to assemble a list of the offsets of all the elements in the file: I.e. I read the length field of each element but discard the contents.

There are two options (in simplified pseudo-code):

```
file = open('...', 'rb')
while True:
    element = array.array('B')
    element.fromfile(file, 4)
    length = int.from_bytes(element, 'big')
    file.seek(length - 4, 1)    # skip reading contents
```

and

```
file = open('...', 'rb')
while True:
    element = array.array('B')
    element.fromfile(file, 4)
    length = int.from_bytes(element, 'big')
    element.fromfile(file, length - 4)   # contents read but never used
```

To my surprise the option that reads the contents only to discard them is about 30-50% faster than the option that skips reading the contents.

In the specific case I was testing on, the elements have lengths of the order of 2 kB while `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` is 8 kB. So here I am often seeking to a position of the file that was already read anyway, which explains the slowdown somewhat.

However, for files with element much larger than the buffer, the option with seek should clearly be faster.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a good way of dynamically choosing the better of two code path? (i.e. Either with full read or with seeking.)
2. What does `file.seek(..., 1)` do to the buffer to result in such a slowdown? Does it clear the read buffer? The seek should be ignored if that part of the file is already in the buffer, no? (Other than moving a pointer along of course.)

Environment:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

---

**Update 1**

Unrelated to any disk transfer speed questions, it appears there are universal performance problems with seeks in streams in python. Even if the stream is not backed by disk but by memory (and thus entirely "cached"). While repeated reads of the stream appear to be additionally buffered somehow, repeated seeks are apparently not.

```
In [1]: from io import BytesIO

In [2]: data = bytearray(int(10e6))

In [3]: stream = BytesIO(data)

In [4]: chunk_size = 1000

In [5]: chunk = bytearray(chunk_size)

In [6]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ...: bytes_read = True
   ...: while bytes_read:
   ...:     bytes_read = stream.readinto(chunk)
   ...: 
The slowest run took 5150.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 1000: 1.54 µs per loop
--> Slowest run: 7.9 ms

In [7]: from math import ceil

In [8]: no_reps = ceil(len(data) / chunk_size)

In [9]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
  ....: for i in range(no_reps):
  ....:    stream.seek(chunk_size)
  ....: 
1 loop, best of 1000: 4.4 ms per loop

In [10]: chunk_size = 1000000

In [11]: chunk = bytearray(chunk_size)

In [12]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ....: bytes_read = True
   ....: while bytes_read:
   ....:     bytes_read = stream.readinto(chunk)
   ....: 
The slowest run took 3428.00 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 1000: 1.54 µs per loop
--> Slowest run: 5.3 ms

In [13]: no_reps = ceil(len(data) / chunk_size)

In [14]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ....: for i in range(no_reps):
   ....:    stream.seek(chunk_size)
   ....: 
The slowest run took 36.69 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 1000: 6.67 µs per loop
--> Slowest run:  245 µs
```

When the stream is new (i.e. not yet read through by python), the disadvantage of seek disappears:

```
In [15]: chunk_size = 1000

In [16]: chunk = bytearray(chunk_size)

In [17]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ....: stream = BytesIO(data)
   ....: bytes_read = True
   ....: while bytes_read:
   ....:     bytes_read = stream.readinto(chunk)
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 1000: 16.7 ms per loop

In [18]: no_reps = ceil(len(data) / chunk_size)

In [19]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ....: stream = BytesIO(data)
   ....: for i in range(no_reps):
   ....:    stream.seek(chunk_size)
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 1000: 15.4 ms per loop

In [20]: chunk_size = 1000000

In [21]: chunk = bytearray(chunk_size)

In [22]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ....: stream = BytesIO(data)
   ....: bytes_read = True
   ....: while bytes_read:
   ....:     bytes_read = stream.readinto(chunk)
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 1000: 13.7 ms per loop

In [23]: no_reps = ceil(len(data) / chunk_size)

In [24]: %%timeit -r1000 -n1
   ....: stream = BytesIO(data)
   ....: for i in range(no_reps):
   ....:    stream.seek(chunk_size)
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 1000: 9.98 ms per loop
```